# Oracle ERROR: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to create the following datatype with 2 functions:

```
-- Employee

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EmployeeType AS OBJECT (
    EmployeeNumber NUMBER,
    EmployeeName VARCHAR2(150),
    EmployeeAddress VARCHAR2(255),
    MAP MEMBER FUNCTION getEmployeeNumber RETURN NUMBER,
    MEMBER FUNCTION CalculateSalary RETURN FLOAT(2)
)
NOT FINAL;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY EmployeeType AS

    MAP MEMBER FUNCTION getEmployeeNumber RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN EmployeeNumber;
    END;
     -- function that can be overriden by subtypes, make abstract
    MEMBER FUNCTION CalculateSalary RETURN FLOAT(2) IS
    BEGIN
         -- function returns empty, has to be overwritten by fulltimeemployee
        RETURN 0.00;
    END;
END;
```

However I keep getting an error stating

```
ERROR: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Error Code: 900

Query = END
```

I am using RazorSQL to execute my queries, I cant seem to get the line number causing this error but through trial and error I have found it to be one of the function descriptions in my `TYPE BODY` definition.

I have tried adding `/` after the last `END;` but it does not help solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `FLOAT(2)` with just `FLOAT`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EmployeeType AS OBJECT (
    EmployeeNumber NUMBER,
    EmployeeName VARCHAR2(150),
    EmployeeAddress VARCHAR2(255),
    MAP MEMBER FUNCTION getEmployeeNumber RETURN NUMBER,
    MEMBER FUNCTION CalculateSalary RETURN FLOAT
)
NOT FINAL;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY EmployeeType AS

    MAP MEMBER FUNCTION getEmployeeNumber RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN EmployeeNumber;
    END;
     -- function that can be overriden by subtypes, make abstract
    MEMBER FUNCTION CalculateSalary RETURN FLOAT IS
    BEGIN
         -- function returns empty, has to be overwritten by fulltimeemployee
        RETURN 0.00;
    END;
END; 
/
```

The documentation for `CREATE TYPE`  doesn't mention this, but you can find the explanation in the topic related to `CREATE FUNCTION` : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_function.htm
RETURN datatype

> **RETURN datatype** 
> For datatype, specify the data type of the return value of the function. The return value can have any data type
>   supported by PL/SQL.
>   ......
> ...... 
> **The data type cannot specify a length, precision, or scale.** 
>   The database derives the length, precision, or scale of the return value
>   from the environment from which the function is called.