# I try to write a function in PL/SQL but it generates an error ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement, what is exactly the reason?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am novice in PL/SQL and i try to write a function that should read data from db control them and return a number, but it generates an error `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`.

```
FUNCTION get_cbk_values             (  TC_CODE             IN    NUMBER,
                                       MERCHANT_DOM          IN   VARCHAR2,
                                       MERCHANT_GROUP     IN    VARCHAR2,
                                       MCC                    IN    VARCHAR2,
                                       COUNTRY                IN  VARCHAR2,
                                       RATE                   OUT  NUMBER,
                                       FIX                    OUT  NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
Response       NUMBER:=1;

CURSOR cur_cbk_param IS SELECT CBA_RATE, CBA_FIX
FROM  cbk_prog_assign_rule WHERE
    CBA_TCO = TC_CODE
AND CBA_DOM_CODE = MERCHANT_DOM 
AND CBA_BMG_CODE = MERCHANT_GROUP
AND CBA_MCC_CODE = MCC
AND CBA_MER_COUN_CODE = COUNTRY;

BEGIN
LOOP
FETCH cur_cbk_param into RATE, FIX;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
Response := 0;
Return(Response);
END;
```

Comment: First, you need to start with `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`, not just `FUNCTION`.  Second, you need to `OPEN` your cursor before you loop through and fetch the results.  Third, you need to `EXIT` the loop `WHEN cur_cbk_param%NOTFOUND`.  Fourth, a cursor loop like this will not throw a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.  Fifth, your function does not `RETURN` a value unless there is an exception.  You must return a value in all situations.

Comment: To effectively diagnose wha'ts happening, you have to provide the instructions to create the table cbk_pro_assing_rule. Some example data will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle ERROR: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946606/oracle-error-ora-00900-invalid-sql-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cursor%ROWCOUNT` to check if no records are returned instead of `no_data_found`.Note that you must have a return statement regardless of `EXCEPTION`. So, you could return 1 for success and 0 for failure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_cbk_values (
    tc_code          IN NUMBER,
    merchant_dom     IN VARCHAR2,
    merchant_group   IN VARCHAR2,
    mcc              IN VARCHAR2,
    country          IN VARCHAR2,
    rate             OUT NUMBER,
    fix              OUT NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER IS

    response   NUMBER := 1;
    CURSOR cur_cbk_param IS SELECT
        cba_rate,
        cba_fix
                            FROM
        cbk_prog_assign_rule
                            WHERE
        cba_tco = tc_code
        AND   cba_dom_code = merchant_dom
        AND   cba_bmg_code = merchant_group
        AND   cba_mcc_code = mcc
        AND   cba_mer_coun_code = country;

BEGIN
    OPEN cur_cbk_param;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_cbk_param INTO rate,fix;
        EXIT WHEN cur_cbk_param%notfound;
    END LOOP;
    IF
        cur_cbk_param%rowcount = 0
    THEN
        response := 0;
    END IF;
    RETURN response;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
--Preferably use dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace or SQLERRM to display or log the message somewhere.
        response := 0;
        RETURN response;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly 3 mistakes:
1- Replace Fuction>>Create or Replace Function
2- Just after Begin add this Line>> Open cur_cbk_param ;
3-  Add this line in Execution section (Just Before Exception)  >>>>Return Response;
Note: No need to use Response inside bracket .